# How to auto update a continuously running Android app without user interaction

Tags: android, auto-update, google-play

We have an app in the Google Play Store that runs in the foreground continuously. The devices that it runs on are out of our control and are not rooted. They run on either Android 4.2 or 4.4.

Our goal is to have the app update to the newest version that we release via the Play Store without user interaction. Restarting the device would be the only acceptable "interaction" option.

We find that a running app does not updated automatically when it is running even if the "automatic update" is turned on.

What is the way to achieve our goal?

Answer (score -1):

Use an Alarm Manager to scheduled your update and then use a create a class and extend the service or IntentService class. Check if theres an internet connection if yes proceed to update like this: Check this link [Android Services - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) In this way you can update even not showing your Activity by using service.

Creating the Alarm Manager:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

For service:

```
    public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

  private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
  public static final String URL = "urlpath";
  public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
  public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
  public static final String RESULT = "result";
  public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.vogella.android.service.receiver";

  public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
  }

  // will be called asynchronously by Android
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
    File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        fileName);
    if (output.exists()) {
      output.delete();
    }

    InputStream stream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

      URL url = new URL(urlPath);
      stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
      fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
      int next = -1;
      while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
        fos.write(next);
      }
      // successfully finished
      result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (stream != null) {
        try {
          stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (fos != null) {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
  }

  private void publishResults(String outputPath, int result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, outputPath);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the code above is an example only.. from the link i given

Comment: This will download updates, but when/where does the actual installation of app update occur?